# How to make current panel draws first then other controls continue resizing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to Winform. I'm facing a difficult issue that all controls need resizing when the main frame is resizing, This causes a lot of '`OnSizeChanged`' events, and now the '`OnPaint`' event of all visible controls (all the controls is showing in the screen in main frame) is really laggy, as you can see in the picture below:

[Laggy drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTuec.png)

I tried to use '`control.BeginInvoke`' to make all invisible controls resize asynchronously, but it seems not work as I expected.

In short, I want to make sure all invisible controls resize after current visible controls drawing done.

Comment: Try sending your main frame a WM_SETREDRAW message.

Comment: As I understand it, you're doing resizing explicitly in your code. Is there a reason for not just using the `Anchor` property of the child controls, or putting them in a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IVSoftware I resize them myself in `FlowLayoutPanel` and let the panel do the relocate for them. By the way I should do more searching about `Anchor`, I don't know how to use this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IVSoftware Oh I searched about `Anchor`, it's just not what I want. Sorry for the code that I can't provide because it's about my job. Simply to explain what I want to do is that, say I have a panel, and there are more panels in this panel, and many controls are in those panels, when then first panel resizes, all panels in side it will resize at the same time, and all controls will do the same. But just 10% of the panels or controls are visible=true, but I want them to be resized already when I switch to show them. Hope I explain my thought well.